# A conditional formatting rule where the cell will be highlighted if it also appears in a list

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

The rule that works is:

```
=MATCH (B1, A2:A6, 0)
```

***Problem is***, it only works for one column at a time (B, in this case). I need it to work across a whole range (B1:Z100).

The end result should look like this:

[image: SO53039023 Q example]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your list range with dollar signs so when you extend the conditional formatting across the whole range, it still looks the value up in the same list:

```
=match(B2,$A$2:$A$6,0)
```

[image]

Comment: oops I did not see you had already answered...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by modifying your formula slightly.

```
=match(B1,$A$1:$A,0)
```

Produced this output:

[image]

In my example, I selected the range for conditional formatting B1:G6.  You need to make your own range.

The formula starts at B1 ( moving through all cells in the range) and the comparison table is fixed as ColA.

Let me know if this is what you want...